# Find Largest number in the array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, arraylist

I am working on a simple program to find the largest number in the file name in python, I have written a piece of code to print the file names from the directory.

```
import glob
for file_name in glob.iglob('src/*/*',recursive=True):
  file_result = file_name.split('/')[2]
  final_string = file_result.split('__')[0]
  versions = final_string.split('.')
  print(versions)
```

This is giving me names like this.

```
['V0', '0', '6']
['V0', '0', '7']
['V0', '0', '42']
['V0', '0', '35']
['V0', '0', '51']
['V0', '0', '1']
['V0', '0', '41']
['V0', '0', '38']
['V0', '0', '45']
```

Now I want to print the largest number from this. I am stuck here, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What would be the output? `['V0', '0', '51']`?

Comment: Do you just  want the number, the index into the array or the whole row as @DaniMesejo just asked?

Comment: Like in the give arrays '51' is the largest so I want to print that

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below

```
import glob

_max = None
for file_name in glob.iglob('src/*/*', recursive=True):
    file_result = file_name.split('/')[2]
    final_string = file_result.split('__')[0]
    versions = final_string.split('.')
    if _max is None:
        _max = versions
    else:
        if int(_max[2]) < int(versions[2]):
            _max = versions
print(_max)
```

Comment: Notice this version doesn't store everything - it only tracks the biggest number, which is jolly sensible

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
versions = []
for file_name in glob.iglob('src/*/*',recursive=True):
  file_result = file_name.split('/')[2]
  final_string = file_result.split('__')[0]
  versions.append(final_string.split('.'))

max_ = 0
for l in versions:
    if int(l[2]) > max_:
        max_ = int(l[2])
        
print(f'Max is {max_}')
```

Comment: max is the name of a built-in function, please avoid using it in your code

Comment: changed it to max_

Answer (score 0):

Just modified your code. It prints now the maximum number you have desired.

```
import glob
list_of_versions = []
for file_name in glob.iglob('src/*/*',recursive=True):
  file_result = file_name.split('/')[2]
  final_string = file_result.split('__')[0]
  versions = final_string.split('.')
  list_of_versions.append(versions)
largest_number = max(int(x[-1]) for x in list_of_versions)
print(largest_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added 2 lines in your code to get the max version number:

```
import glob
max_version = None
for file_name in glob.iglob('src/*/*',recursive=True):
  file_result = file_name.split('/')[2]
  final_string = file_result.split('__')[0]
  versions = final_string.split('.')
  print(versions)
  if max_version and int(versions[-1]) > int(max_version):
      max_version = versions[-1]
      
print (max_version)
```

Answer (score 0):

you search probably for something like

```
files_names = [
    'a/b/V0.0.6__file.txt'
  , 'a/b/V0.0.7__file.txt'
  , 'a/b/V0.0.42__file.txt'
  , 'a/b/V0.0.35__file.txt'
  , 'a/b/V0.0.51__file.txt'
  , 'a/b/V1.0.1__file.txt'
  , 'a/b/V0.0.41__file.txt'
  , 'a/b/V0.0.38__file.txt'
  , 'a/b/V0.1.45__file.txt'
]


max0 = 0
max1 = 0
max2 = 0
res = 'not found'

for file_name in files_names:

  file_result = file_name.split('/')[2]
  final_string = file_result.split('__')[0]
  versions = final_string.split('.')
  ver0 = int(versions[0][1:]);
  ver1 = int(versions[1]);
  ver2 = int(versions[2]);

  if (ver0 > max0) | ((ver0 == max0) & (ver1 > max1)) | ((ver0 == max0) & (ver1 == max1) & (ver2 > max2)):

     max0 = ver0
     max1 = ver1
     max2 = ver2
     res = file_name

print(res)
```